# Read iOS system logs using swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, debugging, logging

Is there a way to read iOS logs that are under Settings>Privacy>Analytics>Analytics Data with some swift (or eventually objective c) code?

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to access the analytics data / crash logs of your device from within your application. There are only two ways to get those data:

1. Connect your device to a Mac or PC and read them out with iTunes
2. Collect the data sent by your users from iTunes Connect

Here is a great article, which describes how to get crash logs and what to do with them: https://www.raywenderlich.com/23704/demystifying-ios-application-crash-logs